# Jackson YAML: support for anchor extensions/overrides

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to use Jackson 2.15.2 `YAMLFactory` to parse the anchor extension syntax:

```
sections:
- &packetInfo
    name: packetInfo
    description: information on a received UDP packet
```

and then later:

```
sections:
-   <<: *packetInfo
    description: something else
```

But I'm getting:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "<<"` , and it's giving all the signs of treating the `<<` as any other field name.

If I remove the `<<:` like this, it loads ok (without the option to override, of course), so the anchor/reference system is working:

```
sections:
-   *packetInfo
```

Does Jackson not support `<<:` extension/overrides? Or is there a Feature switch I need to turn on that I haven't found yet? I've read that handling these is done by a schema, rather than the parser itself.

Comment: @hc_dev although that's a good answer, there's little in the other question or its text about anchor extensions or overrides - it's all about anchors in arrays, which isn't the problem here. I spent most of last night looking for an answer and didn't find that - annoyingly, its mention of `<<` is buried in the code example, and you have to scroll right in an example to see the exception detail. If we close this, shall I go over there and edit the question to be more findable?

Comment: Closed questions stay findable so yours can still serve as pointer to the other question, I'd say that's good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson is known to [not handle references correctly](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/98).

You can use SnakeYAML directly which does support references and the merge key `<<`. Jackson uses SnakeYAML under the hood anyway but somehow screws this up.

SnakeYAML has pretty much the same capabilities as Jackson so there isn't much of a reason why you'd need to stick to Jackson.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation - I feared it might be so! But one excellent reason to stick to Jackson is that our whole schema is defined using Jackson MrBean interface definitions, with `@JsonBackReference` resolution and `@JsonTypeInfo` subtypes - which all works beautifully. I don't think SnakeYAML has any equivalent support, unless I'm wrong? Googling isn't showing anything...

Comment: You have [already answered that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691196/5730279) to a similar question, so I voted to close as duplicate. Agree?

Comment: @hc_dev Right, I added the link to the issue to my answer there (the issue didn't exist when I originally answered that). Good find, I didn't remember it.

Comment: @SusanW Unfortunately SnakeYAML isn't controlled with annotations. Depending on your pipeline, you could preprocess the YAML to drop anchors and aliases before you load it, in your case loading to and dumping via `Object` with SnakeYAML should be enough to remove those, then you can load the result with Jackson. I don't think there's an easier solution.

Comment: @flyx Yeah, we've bought into all the bells and whistles with Jackson! Ok, I've restructured my new YAML schema a bit so the field I need to vary is outside of the structure I want to reuse a lot, which is a reasonably defensible change anyway. So now I'm just using normal anchoring. Thanks for your help!